# Create lines in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I need to make path which connected with different colours of lines, but when I assign the last colour the whole path becomes a single colour. [lines assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYx4P.jpg)

My code is

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.strokeStyle="#f00";
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(150,150);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.strokeStyle="#0f0";
ctx.moveTo(150,150);
ctx.lineTo(350,200);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.strokeStyle="#00f";
ctx.moveTo(350,200);
ctx.lineTo(400,400);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call [ctx.beginPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) to begin each canvas path i.e.

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle="#f00";
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(150,150);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle="#0f0";
ctx.moveTo(150,150);
ctx.lineTo(350,200);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle="#00f";
ctx.moveTo(350,200);
ctx.lineTo(400,400);
ctx.stroke();
```